# Convert delimited data into rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Here I have a source table
Source Table :

```
ID | Log
____________________
1  | Status : New 
   | Assignment : 1
   | Priority : Low
_____________________
2  | Status : In Progress
```

Target Table :

```
ID | Key       | Value
____________________
1  | Status    | New 
1  | Assignment| 1
1  | Priority  | Low
2  | Status    | In Progress
```

Please suggest the approach.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, just to be clear: Does your `Source Table` (the sample you posted above) have just **two** rows, and in the row with `ID = 1`, the text in the `Log` column is on three lines of text (separated by `newline`)? I hope it's not **four** rows, two of which have no value in the `ID` column. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes , you are correct. It has two rows and the text in Log column has newline ..

Comment: Have you considered using SQL*Loader for this task? Of course you would perform some substitutions in the source file (very doable). If you source files are large, it might be the better tool for this type of task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. You seem to have some spaces around the actual tokens that must be removed, so I use the `TRIM()` function for that.

The `WITH` clause is there just for testing (not part of the SQL solution to your question - remove it before testing it against your actual table and columns).

```
with
  source_table ( id, log ) as (
    select 1, 'Status : New 
               Assignment : 1
               Priority : Low'       from dual union all
    select 2, 'Status : In Progress' from dual
  )
select id,
       trim(regexp_substr(log, '(' || chr(10) || '|^)([^:]*):', 1, level, null, 2)) key,
       trim(regexp_substr(log, ':([^:]*)(' || chr(10) || '|$)', 1, level, null, 1)) value
from   source_table
connect by level <= regexp_count(log, ':')
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;

ID  KEY           VALUE              
--  ------------  --------------
 1  Status        New           
 1  Assignment    1             
 1  Priority      Low           
 2  Status        In Progress
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another option; TEST represents your sample data. INTER splits rows (separated by CHR(10)), while the final SELECT utilizes trivial SUBSTR + INSTR combination.

```
SQL> WITH test (id, LOG)
  2       AS (SELECT 1,
  3                     'status: new'
  4                  || CHR (10)
  5                  || 'assignment: 1'
  6                  || CHR (10)
  7                  || 'priority: low'
  8             FROM DUAL
  9           UNION
 10           SELECT 2, 'status: in progress' FROM DUAL),
 11       inter
 12       AS (SELECT id,
 13                  REGEXP_SUBSTR (REPLACE (LOG, CHR (10), ';'),
 14                                 '[^;]+',
 15                                 1,
 16                                 COLUMN_VALUE)
 17                     LOG
 18             FROM test,
 19                  TABLE (
 20                     CAST (
 21                        MULTISET (
 22                               SELECT LEVEL
 23                                 FROM DUAL
 24                           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (LOG, ':') + 1) AS SYS.odcinumberlist)))
 25    SELECT id,
 26           TRIM (SUBSTR (LOG, 1, INSTR (LOG, ':') - 1)) key,
 27           TRIM (SUBSTR (LOG, INSTR (LOG, ':') + 1, LENGTH (LOG))) VALUE
 28      FROM inter
 29     WHERE LOG IS NOT NULL
 30  ORDER BY id;

  ID KEY             VALUE
---- --------------- ---------------
   1 status          new
   1 assignment      1
   1 priority        low
   2 status          in progress

SQL>
```